# VBA code doesn't work if mysql table has unsigned values

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I wrote the vba code below:

```
For x = 1 To Anno.Options.Length
    If Anno.Options(x).Text = CStr(LU(2, CL)) Then
        Anno.selectedIndex = x
        Exit For
    End If
Next x
```

It takes the values of "LU(2, CL)" (from a query in mySql) and uses it to find the option to activate.

Usually it works, but if I set the values ​​as "unsigned" in the database, no longer works and I get the error: " Variable uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic " (This is a translation of the error message in Italian)

Here's my question: 
Is there a way to use "unsigned" type with excel?

Edit (clarifications):

1. LU is an array (type variant) that takes values with: LU = rs.getrows (where rs is a recordset resulted from a query on mySql)
2. If I modify the MySql  database table by setting the field as "unsigned" (I'm talking about one of the fields acquired in LU by the query in the vba code) I get the error.

Comment: What's the unsigned variable in your code?

Comment: I'd need more details on where the data is getting pulled into the array.  It may be as easy as [using a string type for some values](https://convertdb.com/mysql_mssql_mapping)

Comment: I think VBA does not have any 'unsigned' numeric data type. Did you tryed to use Variant?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify it